Caused by: The following artifacts could not be resolved
I am trying to create my own external plugin for sonqrqube scan but facing issue
I have installed sonarqube version : sonarqube-10.7.0.96327
I have installed jdk :
java 17.0.12 2024-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286, mixed mode, sharing)

I have maven installed
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.9.9
Java version: 17.0.12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

I created maven project in eclispe
Version: 2024-09 (4.33.0)
Build id: 20240905-0614

Facing issue in compiling as maven install
Here is my code of pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonarqube-custom-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SonarQube Custom Plugin</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <sonar.version>10.7.0</sonar.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SonarQube API for plugin development -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SonarQube Plugin API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J Logger for SonarQube logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Maven plugin for SonarQube build -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.2155</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Additional logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>com.example.JilDescriptionCheckPlugin</Main-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonarqube</id>
        <url>https://repo.sonarsource.org/content/repositories/sonar-public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

</project>

Here is my code of settings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- Local repository where Maven stores dependencies -->
    <localRepository></localRepository>

    <servers>
        <!-- Configuration for Maven Central -->
        <server>
            <id>central</id>
            <username>XXXXXX</username> 
            <password>XXXXXX</password> 
        </server>
    </servers>

    <mirrors>
        <!-- Mirror for Maven Central -->
        <mirror>
            <id>central</id>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <blocked>false</blocked>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    
    <proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>example-proxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>proxy.example.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <username>proxyuser</username>
        <password>somepassword</password>
        <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>

</settings>

Error I am getting
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m----------------< [0;36mcom.example:sonarqube-custom-plugin[0;1m >-----------------[m
[INFO] [1mBuilding SonarQube Custom Plugin 1.0-SNAPSHOT[m
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[INFO] Downloading from sonarqube: https://repo.sonarsource.org/content/repositories/sonar-public/org/sonarsource/sonarqube/sonar-api/10.7.0/sonar-api-10.7.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading from sonarqube: https://repo.sonarsource.org/content/repositories/sonar-public/org/sonarsource/sonarqube/sonar-plugin-api/10.7.0/sonar-plugin-api-10.7.0.pom
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  2.081 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-04T17:42:56+05:30
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project [36msonarqube-custom-plugin[m: [1;31mCould not collect dependencies for project com.example:sonarqube-custom-plugin:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT[m
[ERROR] [1;31mFailed to read artifact descriptor for org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-api:jar:10.7.0[m
[ERROR] [1;31m  Caused by: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-api:pom:10.7.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-api:pom:10.7.0 from/to sonarqube (https://repo.sonarsource.org/content/repositories/sonar-public/): No such host is known (proxy.example.com)[m
[ERROR] [1;31mFailed to read artifact descriptor for org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-plugin-api:jar:10.7.0[m
[ERROR] [1;31m  Caused by: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-plugin-api:pom:10.7.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.sonarsource.sonarqube:sonar-plugin-api:pom:10.7.0 from/to sonarqube (https://repo.sonarsource.org/content/repositories/sonar-public/): proxy.example.com[m
[ERROR] [1;31m[m
[ERROR] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

How to resolve this
Error

The error says it cannot find the sonar-api with the version you've entered. I cannot find it either. Why do you think 10.7.0 should exist? I cannot find the additional repository you've added and maven central only goes to 9 something or other.

Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

@matt : Can you suggest me the working one

@g00se to be fair, the image is only a copy of the text he's already pasted. It shows the error in red, which the text can't.

@DarshanSalunke you should do a search: https://central.sonatype.com/search?q=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonar-plugin-api . I'm puzzled where you got this idea that there's a 10.7 version.

@k314159 you're right. I missed the text version

This worked for me
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.0.54424</version>
  <name>SonarQube</name>
  <description>Open source platform for continuous inspection of code quality</description>
  <url>http://www.sonarqube.org/</url>
  <organization>
    <name>SonarSource</name>
    <url>http://www.sonarsource.com</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GNU LGPL 3</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>sonarsource-team</id>
      <name>SonarSource Team</name>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube</url>
  </scm>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.22.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-classloader</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-security-python-frontend-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1.15913</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.rpg</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-rpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.3034</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.html</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-html-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.3106</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>animal-sniffer-annotations</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.j2objc</groupId>
            <artifactId>j2objc-annotations</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
            <artifactId>error_prone_annotations</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codelibs.elasticsearch.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>reindex</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.1</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-security-js-frontend-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1.15913</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.abap</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-abap-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.3628</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-security-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1.15913</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.python</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-python-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.9583</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-xml-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.3376</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.11.0.29148</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.everit-org.json-schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20211205</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-security-csharp-frontend-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1.15913</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.cpp</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-cfamily-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.32.0.44918</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.update-center</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-update-center-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0.723</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_common</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.text</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-text-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.120</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.plugins.vb</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-vb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0.3021</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>21.4.0.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.0.202109080827-r</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-matchers</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.config</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-config-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.267</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-security-php-frontend-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1.15913</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nanohttpd</groupId>
        <artifactId>nanohttpd</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.flex</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-flex-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0.2865</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>littleproxy</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-beta-bmp-17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codelibs.elasticsearch.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>analysis-common</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dataprovider</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.73.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.1157</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-kubernetes</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.73</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.php</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-php-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1.8766</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1.jre11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.swift</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-swift-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.5305</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocli</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.dotnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-csharp-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.36.1.44192</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-guava</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.iac</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-iac-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.2012</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.staxmate</groupId>
        <artifactId>staxmate</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>mocksocket</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.orchestrator</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-orchestrator</artifactId>
        <version>3.37.0.87</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-kotlin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.1147</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.210</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.java-diff-utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>diffutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.slang</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-apex-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.3429</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.cobol</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-cobol-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.2.4876</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.tsql</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-tsql-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.4844</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.slang</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-go-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.3429</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.slang</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-ruby-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.3429</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.pli</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-pli-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1.2727</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-security-java-frontend-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1.15913</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.slang</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.3429</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.dotnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-vbnet-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.36.1.44192</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.73</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.jpountz.lz4</groupId>
        <artifactId>lz4</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-channel</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.subethamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>subethasmtp</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sonarsource.plsql</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plsql-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0.4372</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.4</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.eclipsesource.minimal-json</groupId>
        <artifactId>minimal-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.javascript</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-javascript-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.17747</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>  
  
</project>


Your current answer looks to be a "this works for me" code dump answer, and as such probably won't help future visitors to the site, which is the main purpose of the site. Please review the [answer] link, and then consider giving this answer an [edit] and improvement, including adding text that explains the problem and how your proposed solution solves the issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
